# format text in textarea

Tags: html, textarea

I need to display the text retrieved from the database in the `<textarea>` tag. But the thing is that i get this text from db with html tags, like:

```
The line number 1<br>
The line number 2<br>
The line number three<br><br>
```

But when i do:

```
 <textarea>mytext</textarea>
```

Inside the textarea box i get exatly the same text will all the tags, like

```
  The line number 1<br>
  The line number 2<br>
  The line number three<br><br>
```

htmlspecialchars didn't help. It just made it to display entities instead of formatted text, without any tags as if it was show on the web page
What I need is just to show formatted text without possibility to edit it.
How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have HTML tags like `<br>` in your database. Did you use `nl2br` before saving or something? You shouldn't do that. Replace them by fullworthy newlines and it'll work in the textarea.

If you intend to present them in a non-textarea afterwards, then you're allowed to use `nl2br` or like (only at the point of presentation!), or just use CSS `white-space: pre` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following:

```
 &#10;
```

I hope it helps.